# Error While Copying database from SQL server 2005 to SQL server 2008 using Import wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, data-import

I am getting the following error when I am trying to copy database and it's getting stopped at this point.

Error 0xc0047008: Data Flow Task 46: The package contains two objects with the duplicate name of "output column "ErrorCode" (720)" and "output column "ErrorCode" (737)".

Warning 0x80019002: Data Flow Task 46: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are copying a table that has a column named ErrorCode.  If I recall correctly, SSIS raises this error by design since it uses that name in error redirection.

Comment: Correct, see: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/125866/error-0xc0047008-when-trying-to-use-import-export-wizard-for-a-table-with-a-column-named-errorcode